# Ajax GET returns Object #<Object> has no method 'slice' error

Tags: ajax, arrays, angularjs, get, typeerror

I make the following ajax call,

```
$scope.clientList = [];
                     $http({
                     method: 'GET',
                     isArray: true,
                     url: "https://localhost/api/Client",
                     params: sort,

                 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.clientList = data;

                     }). error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                     });
```

I get an array as result in data. 
But I get an error,

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'
```

inspite of adding isArray: true.

anything I am missing ?

Comment: This isn't jQuery. Are you sure the returned object can be converted to an array without any special parsing? Edit, it doesn't look like [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) can use the `isArray` argument, as it is part of [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.clientList = [];
                 $http({
                 method: 'GET',
                 isArray: true,
                 url: "https://localhost/api/Client",
                 params: sort,

             }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.clientList = data.data;

                 }). error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

Sorry was a simple conversion issue. Was assigning the object instead of the array inside the object returned.